# Flutter, access icon size in BottomNavigationBarItem

Tags: flutter, getter

I have a list containing BottomNavigationBarItems.

```
final List<BottomNavigationBarItem> = [...BottomNavigationBarItems...]
```

Now I want to access the icon size from one of the BottomNavigationBarItems.

```
final iconSize = items[index].icon.size;
```

But then I get the error that the getter "size" isn't avaible for the type "Widget".

How can I solve that problem?

[BottomNavigationBarItem Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BottomNavigationBarItem-class.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter `icon` of `BottomNavigationBarItem` has the type `Widget`.
You have to cast it first as `Icon` like this:

```
final iconSize = (items[index].icon as Icon).size;
```